# How to solve error: "The type "" was not found, verify that you are not missing an assembly reference."

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I am getting an error in a page in my Xamarin.Forms project: "The type "" was not found, verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all assemble references have been built".

This is where I am getting the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"

    //Here
    x:Class="FirstApp.Pages.ChatMenuPage"

    xmlns:renderers="clr-namespace:MyProject.Renderers"
    xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:FirstApp"
    xmlns:renderer="clr-namespace:FirstApp.Renderers"
    NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
```

This is my XAML.CS class:

```
using FirstApp.Services;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace FirstApp.Pages
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ChatMenuPage : ContentPage
    {            
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Which xamarin form version you are using.

Comment: @AliAhmad Xamarin.Forms 4.7.0.968

Comment: Xamarin.Forms 4.7 has this issue. Downgrade it to 4.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have InitializeComponent in the constructor, Try rebuilding the project, It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Must Use InitializeComponent in the constructor

```
public partial class ChatMenuPage : ContentPage
{
    public ChatMenuPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: My apologies, I actually have InitializeComponent in the constructor, but I forgot to write it on the question

Answer (score 0):

You have to change namespace declaration in .xaml files.
Also in Appshell.xaml change :

```
*xmlns:{XML namespace name}="clr-namespace:{.NET namespace}"*
```

This link from the tutorial [Create a .NET MAUI app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/tutorials/notes-app/?tutorial-step=4) might help also: